# Excel VBA - Referring between ranges

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Here's my problem:

I have two ranges, r_products and r_ptypes which are from two different sheets, but of same length i.e.

```
Set r_products = Worksheets("Products").Range("A2:A999")
Set r_ptypes = Worksheets("SKUs").Range("B2:B999")
```

I'm searching for something in r_products and I've to select the value at the same position in r_ptypes. The result of Find method is being stored in cellfound. Now, consider the following data:

```
Sheet: Products
   A          B        C          D 
1  Product
2  S1
3  P1
4  P2
5  S2
6  S3

Sheet: SKUs
   A         B         C          D
1           SKU
2           S1-RP003
3           P1-BQ900
4           P2-HE300
5           S2-NB280
6           S3-JN934
```

Now, when I search for S1, cellfound.Row gives me value 2, which is, as I understand, 2nd row in the total worksheet, but is actually 1st row in the range(A2:A999).

When I use this cellfound.Row value to refer to r_ptypes.cells(cellfound.Row), It is taking it as an Index value and returns B3 (P1-BQ900) instead of what I want, i.e. B2 (S1-RP003).

My question is how'll I find out the index number in cellfound? If not possible, how can I use Row number to extract data from r_ptypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.Row` always returns the *absolute* row number of a sheet, not the offset (i.e. index) in the range.

So, just do some minus job to deal with it.

For you example,

```
r_ptypes.Cells(cellfound.Row - r_ptypes.Cells(1).Row + 1)
```

or a little bit neat (?)

```
With r_ptypes
    .Cells(cellfound.Row - .Cells(1).Row + 1)
End With
```

That is, get the row difference between `cellfound` and the first cell and `+ 1` because Excel counts cells from 1.

Comment: That is only an ugly workaround, not a true solution. What happens when the range is moved, because new headings get inserted on one sheet? Instead of hardcoding the number one, he should try to calculate the difference of range start to cell A1.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem.. I want to know if there a way to find the offset, instead of the absolute row number before I move to manipulative solutions...

Comment: @froeschli, @Ashok, see the edit. I am just too lazy, as a programmer expected to be. XD

Comment: @Dante, thank you for your time. It worked. I also managed to get the index value using built in excel function match. Listed it down below.

Answer (score 3):

Dante's solution above works fine. Also, I managed to get the index value using built in excel function Match instead of using Find method of a range. Listing it here for reference.

```
indexval = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("searchvalue", r_products, 0)
```

Using the above, I'm now able to refer the rows in r_ptypes

```
skuvalue = r_ptypes.Rows(indexval).Value
```